# Load a survey with multiple uitextfield and uitextview from local text file

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview, survey, scroll-paging

I am trying to develop an application one of whose features is a survey form. This survey could change from time to time. So I thought, the best way to go about it would be to notify the user of a newer version of the survey and let him download it as a text file. Once downloaded, I would process the text file for some pre-defined *tags* and then load it as a survey form on to his screen with multiple text fields and textviews. Are there any sample codes available that show how we can code these different *tags* that can processed later before showing a survey scroll view.

For example: I can have [Question] for a textview and [Empty] for a textfield and [Multiple] for a multiple choice answer possibility. Similarly [[Start]] and [[End]] for starting and ending the text to be processed.

I have tried to search online for better methods of doing this. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468187/i-want-to-make-a-survey-app-for-ipad-where-should-i-start) question where a webview is suggested, but I need the survey to be available offline so the user could save his answers and continue/change them later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use 1 of the many standard formats used to store and manage data like XML:

```
<Question text="What is...?" />
```

for a basic user input question

```
<Question text="What is...?">
  <Answer text="Option 1">
  <Answer text="Option 2">
</Question>
```

for a multiple choice question

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any open source projects with text files, but there is an open source library that allows you to create a editable PDF. You can take a look at that and see if this library offers you what you are looking for. Anyway here is the link:

http://fastpdfkit.com/